# DataTrigger for DataGridRow background color

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers, styles

I try to Bind a DataGridRow Trigger to set the background to red if my item is critical. Otherwise, I want the `AlternatingRowBackground`. Here is what I have so far:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCritical}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
  </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

It works fine, but it disable the `AlternatingRowBackground` (I read somewhere that it's normal). So I want to do it manually and set the row background myself with that :

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But by doing that it never become red (The Critical binding trigger). I have tried `MultiDataTrigger` and have both condition (IsCritical -> False && Alternate) but the binding fails. I also tried to put both trigger in `Style` and `ControlTemplate`, still doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Style triggers have a higher priority than the ControlTemplate triggers, as discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

What you can do is "target" the element that uses the Background brush and set it directly. So you probably have something like the following in your ControlTemplate:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ... >
```

You can change this to:

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ... >
```

Then change your ControlTemplate DataTrigger to:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCritical}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

This moves the ControlTemplate Trigger's setter's priority up ahead from the Style triggers.

Comment: I can also invert the `DataTrigger` and the `Trigger` from `ControlTemplate` to `Style` to invert precedence.

Comment: @Philippe - That's correct. The last trigger in any given collection will "win".